# How to calculate time differences with condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I have a table with 2 columns consists of: TIME of order and CUSTOMER name.
I need to find the time difference between orders for a specific customer.

```
TIME    CUSTOMER
12/30/2015 23:59:53 STY
12/30/2015 23:50:44 MCL
12/30/2015 23:47:10 STY
12/30/2015 22:30:41 STY
12/30/2015 22:21:20 MCL
12/30/2015 21:53:36 STY
12/30/2015 21:18:32 CHR
12/30/2015 21:07:36 MCL
12/30/2015 20:55:36 CHR
12/30/2015 19:21:49 STY
12/30/2015 18:04:31 MCL
12/30/2015 15:57:28 CHR
```

From the table above, I have to create report on time difference for specific customer. Sample of result is as follow:

CUSTOMER    **STY**

```
**TIME  CUSTOMER    PERIOD**
12/30/2015 23:59:53 STY 00:12:43
12/30/2015 23:47:10 STY 01:16:29
12/30/2015 22:30:41 STY 00:37:05
12/30/2015 21:53:36 STY 02:31:47
12/30/2015 19:21:49 STY 19:21:49
```

CUSTOMER    **MCL**

```
**TIME  CUSTOMER    PERIOD**
12/30/2015 23:50:44 MCL 01:29:24
12/30/2015 22:21:20 MCL 01:13:44
12/30/2015 21:07:36 MCL 03:03:05
12/30/2015 18:04:31 MCL 18:04:31
```

or show all customers:

CUSTOMER    **ALL**

```
**TIME  CUSTOMER    PERIOD**
12/30/2015 23:59:53 STY 00:09:09
12/30/2015 23:50:44 MCL 00:03:34
12/30/2015 23:47:10 STY 01:16:29
12/30/2015 22:30:41 STY 00:09:21
12/30/2015 22:21:20 MCL 00:27:44
12/30/2015 21:53:36 STY 00:35:04
12/30/2015 21:18:32 CHR 00:10:56
12/30/2015 21:07:36 MCL 00:12:00
12/30/2015 20:55:36 CHR 01:33:47
12/30/2015 19:21:49 STY 01:17:18
12/30/2015 18:04:31 MCL 02:07:03
12/30/2015 15:57:28 CHR 15:57:28
```

This report is used to show why a certain customer doesn't put order as frequently as before. Big time difference means a customer doesn't put order for a long period of time. It will also help us detect if there is a serious interruption in our service level.

For "ALL customer" report, it will detect interruption of our service when we receive no order at all for a period of time.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You show entries that are hours or minutes apart on the same day for the customer and format the result for that.  How would you show periods that run into days?

Comment: It happens that we monitor our customer transactions in seconds or minutes. So whenever there is no transaction at all for a specific customer in hours or days, it signals that we have problem to be addressed asap.